# remove button for dynamically created form fields

Tags: jquery

I am developing a website to add, validate and remove sets of form fields (in a single form).

I try to get the code working for the remove button (for each added set of form fields) but without success (despite looking at a few examples at this site and on google).

Any idea where I go wrong with the related code for the remove button?

pls see code below (in particular the code starting with form.find...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" > </script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
            var addForm = $("#add-form");
            var index = 0;

            $("#myForm").validate({
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                    //$(element).next().after(error);
                    //error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
                },
                rules: {} //rules
            }); //validate()

            var getForm = function(index, action) { //returns set of form fields as a string
            return $('\
                <table>\
                <tr>\
                <td> Name </td> <td> Email </td> <td> Phone </td>\
                </tr>\
                <tr>\
                <td> <input id="name' + index + '" name="name' + index + '" /></td>\
                <td><input id="email' + index + '" name="email' + index + '" /></td>\
                <td><input id="phone' + index + '" name="phone' + index + '" /></td>\
                </tr>\
                <a href="#" class="remove">remove fieldset</a>\
                </table>\
                ');
            }//getForm()

            addForm.on("click", function() {
                var form = getForm(++index)
                form.find(".remove").on("click", function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                }); //form.find()
                $("#wrapper").append(form);
                $("#email"+index).rules("add", { required:true,email:true });
            }); //addForm.on()

        }); //$(document).ready
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">
        <div id="wrapper"></div>
        <a href="#" id="add-form">add fieldset</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh sweet god please do not generate HTML like that

Comment: What's wrong with the approach? I'm open for better alternatives...

Comment: check out http://handlebarsjs.com for one way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table structure to make the form, the anchor element to remove the fieldset is not placed inside the table. So when it is placed into the DOM, the remove link will be outside of the table (the parent element to be removed).

http://jsfiddle.net/SG7fG/1/

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
        var addForm = $("#add-form");
        var index = 0;

        $("#myForm").validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
                //$(element).next().after(error);
                //error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
            },
            rules: {} //rules
        }); //validate()

        var getForm = function(index, action) { //returns set of form fields as a string
        return $('\
            <div>\
            <table>\
            <tr>\
            <td> Name </td> <td> Email </td> <td> Phone </td>\
            </tr>\
            <tr>\
            <td> <input id="name' + index + '" name="name' + index + '" /></td>\
            <td><input id="email' + index + '" name="email' + index + '" /></td>\
            <td><input id="phone' + index + '" name="phone' + index + '" /></td>\
            </tr>\
            </table>\
            <a href="#" class="remove">remove fieldset</a>\
            </div>\
            ');
        }//getForm()

        addForm.on("click", function() {
            var form = getForm(++index)

            $("#wrapper").append(form);
            $("#email"+index).rules("add", { required:true,email:true });
            $(".remove").on("click", function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            }); //form.find()
        }); //addForm.on()

    }); //$(document).ready
```

Comment: thnx (also for the explenation), it works. A question wit respect to the remove code: I added an alert('remove') within the remove function ($(".remove").on("click", function() ) and noticed that the remove function is repeated a number of times when pressing remove; this number varies depends on which fieldset you remove. Why is the remove function not always called once?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
form.find(".remove").on("click", function() {
   $(this).parent().remove();
}); //form.find()
$("#wrapper").append(form);
```

to

```
$("#wrapper").append(form);
$(".remove").unbind("click").on("click", function() {
   $(this).parent().remove();
}); //form.find()
```

You need to place your *form* in the DOM, so you cannot bind before you do it.
I also changed to use `$(".remove")` to unbind existing clicks, and bind it back including in the newly added one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of remove button

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" > </script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
            var addForm = $("#add-form");
            var index = 0;

            $("#myForm").validate({
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                },
                rules: {}
            });

            var getForm = function(index, action) {
            return $('\
                <table id="tbl' + index +'">\
                <tr>\
                <td> Name </td> <td> Email </td> <td> Phone </td>\
                </tr>\
                <tr>\
                <td> <input id="name' + index + '" name="name' + index + '" /></td>\
                <td><input id="email' + index + '" name="email' + index + '" /></td>\
                <td><input id="phone' + index + '" name="phone' + index + '" /></td>\
                </tr>\
                <a href="#" id="remove-form' + index + '" data-index="' + index + '">remove fieldset</a>\
                </table>\
                ');
            }

            addForm.on("click", function() {
                var form = getForm(++index)
                form.find(".remove").on("click", function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                }); //form.find()
                $("#wrapper").append(form);
                $("#email"+index).rules("add", { required:true,email:true });

                $("#remove-form"+index).on("click", function() {
            var currentIndex = $(this).data( "index" );
                    $("#tbl" + currentIndex).remove();
                });
            });

        }); //$(document).ready
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">
        <div id="wrapper"></div>
        <a href="#" id="add-form">add fieldset</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```